# Integrate radio button into table PHP / Yii 2

Tags: php, html, yii2

how can i integrate a radio button into a table? I have this modal where I need to put a radio button on each table, the radio button will contain some kind of value to differentiate the tables. Here is an output of the table that will be integrated with a radio button.

[image]

The value of the radio button I am trying to put on each table is the variable `$group` in this for loop.

```
  <div class="modal-body">
  <?php $getSectionGroup = SiteController::Getsectiongroup(); ?>
  <?php for ($group=1; $group <= $getSectionGroup; $group++): //group variable will be used in getBlock ?>
    <?php $getBlock = SiteController::GetBlock(Yii::$app->user->identity->curriculumcode, Yii::$app->user->identity->year,
     Yii::$app->user->identity->term, $group); ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="studentTable">
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Schedule</th>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Slots</th>
      <th>Status</th>
  <?php foreach($getBlock as $values): ?>

          <tr>
            <td><?= $values['subjectcode']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $values['schedday'] . ' ' . $values['schedtime'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $values['section'] ?></td>
            <td><?= '....' ?></td>
            <td><?= $values['slots'] ?></td>
            <td><?= '....' ?></td>
          </tr>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
      </table>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </div>
```

Tell me if you need more info. Thanks.

**EDIT**

View (Mainpage)

```
<div class="modal-body">

          <?php $getSectionGroup = SiteController::Getsectiongroup(); ?>
          <?php for ($group=1; $group <= $getSectionGroup; $group++): //group variable will be used in getBlock ?>
            <?php $getBlock = SiteController::GetBlock(Yii::$app->user->identity->curriculumcode, Yii::$app->user->identity->year,
             Yii::$app->user->identity->term, $group); ?>

<form action="" method="post">
             <input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php echo $group?>">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="studentTable">
              <th>Subject</th>
              <th>Schedule</th>
              <th>Section</th>
              <th>Action</th>
              <th>Slots</th>
              <th>Status</th>
          <?php foreach($getBlock as $values): ?>

                  <tr>
                    <td><?= $values['subjectcode']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $values['schedday'] . ' ' . $values['schedtime'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $values['section'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= '....' ?></td>
                    <td><?= $values['slots'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= '....' ?></td>
                  </tr>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
              </table>
            <?php endfor; ?>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="submit" value="Go">
           <?php // Html::a('<b>Submit</b>',
                 //                        ['site/addblock'],
                   //                     ['class' => 'btn-info btn-transparent btn-large', 'data-method' => 'get']) ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
          </form>
```

Action

```
public function actionMain(){
     // $model = new MainModel();
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            //return $this->goHome();
            // $this->layout = 'userlayout';
            // return $this->render('mainpage');
            $this->redirect('site/index',302);
            }
            $output = var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post('blockform'));
          $this->layout = 'userlayout';
          return $this->render('mainpage', ['outputblockform' => $output]);
    }
```

New error

[image]

Comment: maybe i am wrong, but don't you need to `print`/`echo` `<?= $values['subjectcode']; ?>` ?

Comment: In yii 2, `<?= ?>` means echo

Comment: oh, sorry didn't knew am not a expert though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use [GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html) for table. You may get less work to do in future because it automatically generates necessary divs and boostrap style. But let's say you're doing this and you want to use radio button. Now it a little depends on how many radio buttons you want to implement into one cell.

One example:

```
<td>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="some_name" value="1"> Action1
    <input type="radio" name="some_name" value="2"> <?= $values['subjectcode']; // Or this ?>
    <input type="radio" name="some_name" value="3"> Action3
    <br><input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
</td>
```

This will look something like this:

3 different radio buttons with name `some_name` and there are 3 different options to select from. Once selected, there is a button in the same cell that allow you to click on it and then specific action is triggered.

Comment: Do you know how to get the value of the radio button? I want to process it in a query when the user presses submit.

Comment: Or is it possible to put it in a url? like `<?= Html::a('<b>Submit</b>',
                                         ['site/addblock'],//value should be around here
                                        ['class' => 'btn-info btn-transparent btn-large', 'data-method' => 'get']) ?>`

Comment: @user827391012 You can get the value from this (in controller): `Yii::$app->request->post('some_name');`.

Comment: you mean the controller where I am loading the page? Or should I make a new controller?

Comment: @user827391012 This is a place for your `Yii::$app->request->isPost();` Function should be current action (perhaps `view`?). Try to write `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post('some_name'); exit;` in that action.

Comment: @user827391012 If you still have some issues or questions, I can (perhaps) answer them. Just tell me what you don't understand. :)

Comment: @user827391012 I see. This coild take some time and writin space... I would suggest you to write me an email for further help because comments is not a good place for long conversation. :)